How to use @For with ng-template?
I am new to PrimeNG and current using  PrimeNG table. I have been using @for to loop through content and populate table
Example:
@for (item of items; track item.id){
<tr>
    <td>{{item.type || 'N/A'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name || 'N/A'}}</td>
<tr>

Based on PrimeNG example. It loops through using ng-template:
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
   <tr>
   <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
   <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
   <tr>
</ng-template>

I am using Angular 17.3.2. Would like to understand what's the difference and how can I use @for with primeng table.
Want to understand what's the difference and how can I use @for with primeng table.

You don't need the @for/*ngFor as with pTemplate="body", the PrimeNG table will render the row automatically based on the provided array value to [value]. https://primeng.org/table#template

Thanks @YongShun. So for table we will go with pTemplate and for other non table element e.g.  we can go with @for/*ngFor?

Ya. It depends on how you construct the HTML element, whether using the library/component or not such as PrimeNG. Like PrimeNG, it has a built-in API to simplify the HTML construction (you do not need to build the whole table element with style from scratch).
